# GoG on Linux installation Procedure

Tags: 13.04, windows, wine, python, games

I wanted to install GoG on Linux ( http://gogonlinux.com/ ) and as I went through the install process (which is for Ubuntu12.04) and the result is that I have all the files built by python, but no executable or any way to access the client at all.

I've checked the forums there, but I don't believe (since it's beta) that I will receive any possible insight.

Does anyone know how to create the physical linking or what exactly I've ignored?

Comment: Have you checked the [Getting Started](http://gogonlinux.com/getting_started/) page? If you follow the instructions there, you should end up with a launch link for the Gog Tux program from your application menu, you can find it under the games tab.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, but where is the Games tab in Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience. I search through my file system. I found it at:
/usr/local/share/application/Gog Tux.txt
I double clicked on Gog Tux and it opened right up.